# Software to find company domain email id of any employee within organization

Tags: email, email-client

Is there any software to find company domain email id of any employee for any organization ? I search Google but cant find.Please suggest any plugin or software for that.

Comment: refer [this](https://moz.com/ugc/14-easy-ways-to-find-any-email-address-in-10-minutes-or-less).

Comment: If you are not member of this organization yourself, this is not possible. Otherwise spamers would have an easy life in finding valid email addresses.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @CPerkins Now you are suggesting something about the OP. Not nice.

Comment: I agree.  Comment deleted.